# JSONParser to ListView need double

Tags: android, json

I have a ListView that shows the searched Title of the movie from OMDBAPI and when click the search btn i need to click twice indstead of once.

Please Help.

Here's the code:

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    static ArrayList<String> movieList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        try {

            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.connect();
            InputStream stream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
            String line = "";
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                builder.append(line);

            }
            return builder.toString();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally {
            if(httpURLConnection != null){
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            }
            try {
                if (reader != null){
                    reader.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return "Failed Connection";
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Search");
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 1; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject finalJsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                String titleOfMovie = finalJsonObject.getString("Title");
                movieList.add(titleOfMovie);
                stringBuilder.append(movieList);
                finalJsonObject.get("Title");

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the mainActivivty:

```
public class Main2ActivityWeb extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText searchBar;
    ListView listOfMovies;
    Button searchBtn;
    Button deleteBtn;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    String url = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2_activity_web);

        searchBar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etsearch);
        listOfMovies = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMovies);
        searchBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSearch);
        deleteBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);

        searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                arrayAdapter = null;
                final String search = url + searchBar.getText().toString();
                new JSONParser().execute(search);
                ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(JSONParser.movieList);
                arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Main2ActivityWeb.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
                listOfMovies.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                if (arrayAdapter !=null){
                    JSONParser.movieList.clear();
                }



            }
        });

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listOfMovies.setAdapter(null);
                JSONParser.movieList.clear();
                searchBar.setText("");
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Use Volley's JSONObjectRequest. Much easier than using an AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you seem to not understand the concept that an AsyncTask is **asyncronous**, so

```
new JSONParser().execute(search);
```

Will not store anything into `JSONParser.movieList` until the `onPostExecute` has completed.

Meanwhile, you continue to **synchronously** run

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>(JSONParser.movieList);
```

Which is mostly likely empty the first time you click the button because you are still waiting for the AsyncTask to finish in the background to parse the JSON.

On the second click of the button, you are starting a new request for the JSON, but the results you see are from the first request.

---

One way to deal with that is callbacks, like Volley, Retrofit/OkHttp would do, but you can also move around the objects that you use so that they execute in the correct order. For example, give the AsyncTask the ArrayAdapter instead of having it maintain it's own ArrayList

```
private ArrayList<String> list;

...

onCreate() {
    listOfMovies = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMovies);
    list = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Main2ActivityWeb.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    listOfMovies.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

...
    onClick() {
        ...
        new JSONParser(arrayAdapter).execute(search);
    }
}
```

In the AsyncTask

```
public class JSONParser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    public JSONParser(ArrayAdapter<String> adapter) {
        this.adapter = adapter;
    }

    ...

    onPostExectute() {
        for (...) {
           adapter.add(titleOfMovie);
        }
        apdater.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```